# Регулярное выражение возвращающее предложение с определённым словом

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

### Суть

Есть некий текст, состоящий (как не странно) из предложений :) В одном (или нескольких) предложений(ях), присутствует одно и то же слово, например «гербарий», которое может находиться в начале, внутри или конце предложения. Предложением может считаться набор слов, первое из которых, начинается с любой цифры или буквы в верхнем регистре `[0-9А-ЯA-Z]`, перед которыми могут быть точка и пробел `[\.\s]` или не может быть ничего, и оканчивающийся точкой `[\.]`.

### Задача

Вытащить из текста (`$row['text']`) первое предложение содержащие слово (`$termin`) и сохранить в переменную (`$match`). Само слово надо «подсветить», например, «упаковав» в `<span style="color:red">`.

Сам я в регулярках не силён, всю ночь почти, искал в сети, пробовал конструировать в онлайн-сервисах, ничегошеньки не выходит. Начинаешь составлять, вроде бы всё «логично», но они «магическим» образом не работают. Создаётся устойчивое впечатление, что мастерством составления регулярок, обладают лишь профессиональные шаманы и чудотворцы. Очень надеюсь на помощь волшебников :)

Comment: Если предложение всегда? оканчивается точкой, то как вначале следующего предложения "или не может быть ничего"? Набор входных данных для поиска упростил бы решение.

Comment: Ну, если в параграфе предложение первое, то перед ним ничего быть не может же :) А это «_Набор входных данных для поиска упростил бы решение_» как?

Answer (score 1):

Сперва найти предложение, потом обернуть искомое слово в html-теги:

```
$row['text'] = '
Есть 1 некий текст, состоящий (как не странно) из предложений :) В одном (или нескольких) предложений(ях), присутствует одно и то же слово, например, которое может находиться в начале, внутри или конце предложения.

Есть 2 некий текст, состоящий (как не странно) из предложений :) В одном (или нескольких) предложений(ях), присутствует одно и то же слово, например «гербарий», которое может находиться в начале, внутри или конце предложения.

Есть 3 некий текст, состоящий (как не странно) из предложений :) В одном (или нескольких) предложений(ях), присутствует одно и то же слово, например «гербарий», которое может находиться в начале, внутри или конце предложения.
';

$termin = 'гербарий';

if (preg_match("~[А-ЯЁ].+{$termin}.+~", $row['text'], $arr)) {
    $match = preg_replace("~{$termin}~", '<span style="color:red">$0</span>', $arr[0]);
}

echo $match;
```

Comment: Отлично выводит! Огромное спасибо! Хотел только спросить. А почему в одном случае выводит одно предложение, а в других два, три? Так надо?)

Comment: И, кстати, если термин в начале предложения — не ищет :(

Comment: @Linne попробуйте этот regexp: https://regex101.com/r/hDD9wV/2 `(?=[^.]*(?:Г|г)ербарий)(?:^|[A-ZА-Я0-9Ё])[^.]+\.` UPD: не сразу обратил внимание что этот вопрос уже изжил себя.

Answer (score 0):

вот?

```
"~\.[^\.]*(гербарий)+.*(?=\.)~"
```

выделяет предложение.

Comment: Извините за уточнение, "_вроде как_" или всё таки возвращает? До публикации можно же проверить.